# Работа с CSV файлом

Tags: java

Требуется создать телефоную книгу. Одна из опций, которая меня ставит в тупик:

> Когда пользователь выбирает "Н", приложение требует ввода имени,
>   телефона и город(опционально - т.е можно и не вводить). Приложение
>   автоматически генерирует ID для новой записи. Не позволяется ввод
>   дублированых значений по имени и номеру. Java консольное приложение.

Пожалуйста дайте идеи в реализации.

Comment: Ну где не позволяются дубли сразу вспоминаем про Set и Map с их имплементациями HashSet и HashMap. Телефонную книгу можно организовать как сет из номеров телефонов или мэп, у которого ключами будут номера телефонов, а значениями - мэпы с данными контактов.

Comment: Так а с чем проблема-то? Не можете считать, не выходит парсить/искать?

Comment: Проблема генерирования ID в CSV

Comment: Разве номер телефона не уникален? Зачем ещё по имени? К тому же один человек в праве иметь несколько номеров. Также номер телефона можно использовать в качестве ID, надо только все номера привести к общему формату.

Answer (score 1):

Решил вот таким способом:

```
private static int getLastColumnValue() {
    try {

        FileReader fr = new FileReader("myPhoneBook.csv");
        LineNumberReader lnr = new LineNumberReader(fr);

        int linenumber = 0;

        while (lnr.readLine() != null) {
            linenumber++;
        }

        lnr.close();
        return linenumber++;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    return Integer.parseInt(null);
}
```

Далее поставляю его `csvOutput.write(new String(String.valueOf(getLastColumnValue())));`
Используется OpenCSV библиотека